Property 'value' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }' but required in type 'ChakraProviderProps'.ts(2741)
I am trying ChakraUI for my project (using React, Vite, and TypeScript) by learning from a youtube. I am using version 3.0.2.
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^3.0.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "framer-motion": "^11.11.11",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.10",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^5.0.1"
  }
}

As you can see that I have installed necessary dependencies required for mine project with typescript. But when I try to import the ChakraProvider like this in main.tsx like below:
import {ChakraProvider} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
import App from "./App"

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

I trying passing a prop to the ChakraProvider called value and gave it a value undefined so that the TypeScript can see some value in the props. Like this:
<ChakraProvider value={undefined}> 

But I get this error after that:

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SystemContext'.ts(2322)
provider.d.ts(4, 5): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ChakraProviderProps'

Why is that and how can I fix it?

are you following mosh hamedani's react tutorial? @Rem ON

The value prop allows you to specify your styling system. You can pass in a custom value if you are making changes to Chakra's defaults, but otherwise you need to pass in defaultSystem from Chakra:
import { defaultSystem } from "@chakra-ui/react"

...

<ChakraProvider value={defaultSystem}>
   <App />
</ChakraProvider>

